# Toggle ul (submenu)

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

How do I show the first `<ul>` inside a `<li>`, when I hover on the `<li>`?

Comment: What browser's do you support? You may not need JavaScript.

Comment: Considering limitations with cross-browser CSS2+, you're probably better off to use JS, regardless of what you choose to support. You really should support as many as you can anyway. Not to mention that jQuery has taken the guesswork out of a lot of the cross-browser issues for you. :D

Comment: @nalroff, there is nothing special regarding the `:hover` psuedo class. It should have wide support - IE7+, Safari, Chrome, Opera, FF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="firstLevel">
        <ul></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="firstLevel"></li>
    <li class="firstLevel"></li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$('li.firstLevel').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').show();
},
function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').hide();
});
```

Note: this is only necessary for browsers that do not support `hover` on lis (IE6)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("ul.menu>li").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).children("ul:first").show();
  },
  function() {
    $(this).children("ul:first").hide();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to advocate CSS. If you are not supporting IE6 and don't require a special effect, I suggest doing this with CSS:

```
ul.menu li > ul {
  display: none;
}

ul.menu li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```